# making Excel Instance visible without giving it the focus

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I generate excel reports with access. And I want to avoid that users suddenly have a pop-up excel window in the middle of their work.

And this is my question. I generate the report in Excel, everything is fine. But as soon as the program is turned to visible, it can happen that a User is in the middle of a eMail and then overwrites sth. in the excel report, before he knows it. 
So idealy excel should become visible only in the background, without getting the focus.

But I dont know how to programm that in vba access

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could always output the file do a directory and let them open it up if this is such a big issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output the Excel file to a folder/directory or the same filepath as the Database, you can use :

```
Dim outputFileName As String

  outputFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\Test Output" & Format(Date, "MMddyyyy") & ".xlsx"
  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "usersQry", outputFileName, True
```

More specifically, though, it looks like you could utilize something like this:

```
If MsgBox("Save file as " & CurrentProject.Path & "\Reports\Blah " & Format(Date, "MMddyyyy") & ".xlsx. " & _
        "Open file in Excel?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2) = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
        Dim xlTmp As Excel.Application
        Set xlTmp = New Excel.Application
        xlTmp.Workbooks.Open outputFileName
        xlTmp.Visible = True  ' You can change this to false
End If
```

If you run into an error with the `Excel.Application` throwing the user-defined type" error, use this initialization :

```
Dim xlTmp as object
Set xlTmp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlTmp.Workbooks.Open outputFileName
xlTmp.Visible = True  ' You can change this to false
```

This happens because you're probably missing the Excel Object Library, so Access doesn't know what `Excel.Application` means.